# How to define a value on "Creating default object from empty value" error

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings

I knew many question about this, I try to read but still got this error message on my Wordpress :

"Creating default object from empty value in /home/forthemde/public_html/wp-content/themes/mayadeep/admin/admin.php on line 225"

Here the code on `admin.php` and:

```
 function upfw_setup_theme_options(){
     $up_options_db = get_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME);
     global $up_options;
     //Check if options are stored properly
     if( isset($up_options_db) && is_array($up_options_db) ):
         //Check array to an object
         foreach ($up_options_db as $k => $v) {
                 $up_options -> {$k} = $v;
         }
     else:
         do_action('upfw_theme_activation');
     endif;
 }
 add_action('upfw_theme_init','upfw_setup_theme_options',10);
 add_action('upfw_admin_init','upfw_setup_theme_options',100);
```

Line 225 is here:

```
 $up_options -> {$k} = $v;
```

I try to fix by myself, but no result. Please help me, really appreciate for any help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because the global object `global $up_options` is not defined.

Try to `var_dump $up_options`, it might be null.

Also check if you have spelled the variable name correctly.

Run this code, and check the output:

```
function upfw_setup_theme_options(){
     $up_options_db = get_option('up_themes_'.UPTHEMES_SHORT_NAME);
     global $up_options;

 $up_options = new stdClass();

     //Check if options are stored properly
     if( isset($up_options_db) && is_array($up_options_db) ):
         //Check array to an object
         foreach ($up_options_db as $k => $v) {
                 $up_options -> {$k} = $v;
         }
     else:
         do_action('upfw_theme_activation');
     endif;
 }
 add_action('upfw_theme_init','upfw_setup_theme_options');
 add_action('upfw_admin_init','upfw_setup_theme_options');
```

Comment: Thanks, MortalViews. Unfortunatelly, I am not familiar with the code. How can I var_dump $up_options? Please help. Really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Thanks, Mortal. I tried but unfortunately did not work. My page become blank, and just display a text "NULL". The error code is in line 225:  $up_options -> {$k} = $v;

Comment: ya, that's cos of the exit(); 'null' means the $up_option object is not defined.that's the **problem**.You need to make sure the global object is created before using it.  var_dump, and exit was for debugging. you should remove it from your actual code, it's not a FIX.

Comment: When I delete the exit(); I got this notify: NULL
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp-PHPBARU\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\forthemde\admin\admin.php on line 233

Comment: that error is cos the object $up_option is having null value.you can't call property of a 'null' object.

Comment: I change  $user_options = new stdClass(); to be  $up_options= new stdClass(); and worked like a charm! Thank you very much, dear friend. You save my day.

Comment: you are welcome. you were using the holding pattern wordpress theme?

Comment: I am so sorry, I am not sure about "holding pattern wordpress theme." Apologize with my English.